# Django Select 2 Widget not working , Field rendered but styles not applied

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, django-select2

I have been trying to use multiple select using django-select2 widget for a while

Step-1: I installed django-select2 using `pip install django-select2`

Step-2: Added it the installed app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
django_select2
...
]
```

Step-3: I added the below to `settings.py`

```
SELECT2_JS = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"
SELECT2_CSS = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css"
SELECT2_I18N_PATH = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/i18n"
```

Step 4: I tried it using the widgets

```py
from django_select2.forms import Select2MultipleWidget
class ClientForm(AppModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ['client_website']
        widgets = {
            'point_of_contact': Select2MultipleWidget
        }
```

Step 5: Just render the form without any loop of any sort

```
{{ client_form }}
```

The result is

[image]

No style is applied to the select.

I also tried including the styles and scripts in the head tag (Didn't help).

I belive the widget is working, because when i switch from `Select2MultipleWidget` to `Select2Widget` , It changes to a single select

```html
<select name="point_of_contact" lang="None" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-theme="default" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="" id="id_point_of_contact" class="django-select2" multiple="">
  <option value="2">Test</option>

  <option value="1">Tester</option>

</select>
```

The above is the html rendered for the multi select widget by django

Kindly help in getting the functionality of django-select2

Comment: Did you add select2 urls and form media in template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `SELECT2_JS` and `SELECT2_CSS` points to the respective Cloudflare CDN. Use it when you want to load a specific version from CDN or when you want to load from local storage.

Make sure to add select2 url patterns to the main urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("select2/", include("django_select2.urls")),
    # other patterns
]
```

and add form assets in template file:

```html
<!-- To render stylesheet link tags of select2 -->
{{ client_form.media.css }}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ client_form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- Add JQuery script -->
<!-- To render script tags of select2 -->
{{ client_form.media.js }}
```

Installation and Quick start guides are available here:
https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation
https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start

Django Form Assets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/media/